# I2C instability between a pair of Raspberry Pi

Tags: i2c

I have a connected a Raspberry Pi Zero (1.3, no W, running `Raspbian 10 (buster) lite`) as an I2C slave (clock:`GPIO18`,data:`GPIO19`) to a Raspberry Pi 3b (running `Ubuntu 20.04.1`) as an I2C master(clock:`GPIO3`,data:`GPIO2`).

- The wiring is [Dupont style connectors of approximately 20cm length](https://robu.in/product/20cm-dupont-wire-color-jumper-cable-2-54mm-1p-1p-female-female-40pcs/) connected directly between the GPIO headers.
- The only configuration done is to uncomment the `dtparam=i2c_arm=on` in the config.txt of the boot/firmware directory on both the raspberry pi 3B and the Zero.
- Packages installed are `python3-pigpio` and dependencies on the Pi Zero, and `python3-smbus` on the Pi 3b.

There is barely any load on either of the nodes:

```
samveen@pi3:~$ cat /proc/loadavg
0.00 0.00 0.00 1/171 2538
...
pi@pi0:~$ cat /proc/loadavg
0.20 0.21 0.18 1/81 720
```

The connection works when tested with the [`python3-pigpio` I2C slave example](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_bsc_arduino_py) and a simple `python3-smbus` script on the master:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import smbus
    import time

    DEVICE_BUS = 1
    DEVICE_ADDR = 0x09
    bus = smbus.SMBus(DEVICE_BUS)

    def sendData(slaveAddress,reg,data):
        intsOfData = list(map(ord, data))
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(DEVICE_ADDR, reg, intsOfData)

    message=""
    for c in '0123456789abcdef01234567890abcdef0':
        message+=c
        print("sending {} bytes".format(len(message)))
        sendData(DEVICE_ADDR,0x00,message)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Observations:

- The communication is rock solid up while message length is 16 bytes or less.
- Messages longer than 16 bytes do not deliver reliably: the first 16 bytes get delivered fine, but anything past that is non-deterministically received. Out of the 32 messages sent per run of the above script, the best run had only 3 of the 16 longer-that-16-byte messages received correctly.

Question:

- What can I do to improve the I2C communication between the 2, so that I have completely reliable messaging?

References:

- [Raspberry as an I2C SLAVE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76109/raspberry-as-an-i2c-slave)
- [i2c-tools and python3-smbus source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/i2c-tools/i2c-tools.git/tree/py-smbus) which wasn't as helpful as expected.
- [Random yet useful search result for python3-smbus documentation](https://www.electronicwings.com/raspberry-pi/python-based-i2c-functions-for-raspberry-pi), as the package `help` in `python` doesn't explain the meaning of the parameter `com`...
- [Kernel I2C documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/smbus-protocol) which was required to make sense of the i2c-tools sources.

Comment: Isn't the hardware slave I2C buffer 16 bytes?  I suggest you limit messages to that size.

Comment: @joan would you point me to the correct documentation for this? (my hope's that you're the best person to answer all `pigpio` questions :D). also the possibility of how I can extend the 16 byte buffer into a 32 byte buffer? As in which portion of the sources, ligpigpio or pigpiod or the python lib code? I am not in control of message length (final communication endpoint on the master end will not be my code).